# How can I replace Openshift's built-in php in Do-It-Yourself application?

Tags: php, openshift

I was trying to install PHP 5.6.11 into Openshift "Do-it-Yourself 0.1". After the installation, I restarted all the services via "ctl_all restart". But after that, when I run "php -v", it showed:

```
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul  3 2015 03:10:33)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

How can I replace this built-in version of PHP with PHP 5.6.11? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that your new version's bin directory is specified in your PATH before the other version, that way it will pick up that php version first.

Comment: Thanks @corey112358 for the help. Now I use PATH=mypath:$PATH
export PATH and I can use PHP 5.6.11 in Openshift now. But the problem is once I restarted this session, I have to do it again. How can I make this change permanent? Thanks.

Comment: You should probably use an action hook to set it when the application is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

I found this post: https://forums.openshift.com/permanently-add-to-path to permanently add new bin to PATH by etting the PATH variable in
the app's pre_start action hook ($app/.openshift/action_hooks/pre_start_$apptype).

Hope it can help.